# Complex numbers - finding minimum value

Tags: complex-numbers

For all complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ satisfying $|z_1|=12$ and $|z_2-3-4i|=5$ , find the minimum value of $|z_1-z_2|$

Can we go like this :

Let $z_1 = x +iy$ therefore $|z_1| = \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}$ and $z_2 = x_2+ iy_2$

$|z_2-3-4i| = \sqrt{(x_2-3)^2+ (y_2-4)^2}$ so $x_2^2-6x_2+9+y_2^2-8y_2+16 =25$ ( squaring both sides) ..
Please guide if it is correct..

Comment: is that $z_1$ in $|z-1-z_2|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another hint:

[image]

Hence, the maximum is $22$ and the minimum is $2$ but you should prove this.

Comment: Don't you mean $2$?  We are looking for the minimum distance.

Answer (score 4):

An algebraic method

$$
|z_1 - z_2 | \geq |z_1| - |z_2| \\
|z_2-(3+4i)| \geq |z_2| - 5 \\
|z_2|\leq 10\\
|z_1 - z_2 | \geq 12-10=2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw the sets $\mathcal{A} = \{z_1: |z_1| = 12\}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \{z_2: |z_2-3-4i| = 5\}$ in the complex plane (both will be circles). Now draw the set $\mathcal{B}' = \{1+z_2:|z_2-3-4i| = 5\}$, which will be "$\mathcal{B}$ shifted one unit to the right." You would like to find the two closest points of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$. The answer will be obvious as soon as you draw these circles.

Comment: nice solution Lord Soth.....

Comment: @juantheron, I am  new to complex numbers and trying to understand why $1+z_{2}$ is plotted in this scenario?